# BST printing without mutating?

Tags: printing, scheme, racket, binary-search-tree

So i basically want to printbst's .. here is a little more detail

Provide a function (printbst t) that prints a BST constructed from BST as provided by bst.rkt in the following format:

-Each node in the BST should be printed on a separate line;

-the left subtree should be printed after the root;

-The right subtree should be printed before the root;

-The key value should be indented by 2d spaces where d is its depth, or distance from the root. That is, the root should not be indented, the keys in its subtrees should be intended 2 spaces, the keys in their subtrees 4 spaces, and so on.

For example, the complete tree containing {1,2,3,4,5,6} would be printed like this:

```
  6
    5
4
    3
  2
    1
```

Observe that if you rotate the output clockwise and connect each node to its subtrees, you arrive at the conventional graphical representation of the tree. Do not use mutation.

Here is what i have so far:

```
#lang racket
;;Note: struct-out exports all functions associated with the structure
(provide (struct-out BST))


(define-struct BST (key left right) #:transparent)

(define (depth key bst)
  (cond
    [(or (empty? bst) (= key (BST-key bst))) 0]
    [else (+ 1 (depth key (BST-right bst)) (depth key (BST-left bst)))]))

(define (indent int)
  (cond
    [(= int 0) ""]
    [else "  " (indent (sub1 int))]))

(define (printbst t)
  (cond
    [(empty? t) (newline)]
    [(and (empty? (BST-right t)) (empty? (BST-left t))) 
     (printf "~a~a" (indent (depth (BST-key t) t)) (BST-key t))]))
```

My printbst only prints a tree with one node thou .... i have an idea but it involves mutation, which i can't use :( ..... Any suggestions ? Should i change my approach to the problem all together?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, you're going to want to restructure this more or less completely.

On the bright side, I like your indent function :)

The easiest way to write this problem involves making recursive calls on the subtrees. I hope I'm not giving away too much when I tell you that in order to print a subtree, there's one extra piece of information that you need.

...

Based on our discussion below, I'm going to first suggest that you develop the closely related recursive program that prints out the desired numbers *with no indentation*. So then the correct output would be:

```
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Updating that program to the one that handles indentation is just a question of passing along a single extra piece of information.

P.S.: questions like this that produce output are almost impossible to write good test cases for, and consequently not great for homework. I hope for your sake that you have lots of other problems that *don't* involve output....

Comment: yea that's wht i was thinking , i need to first hit the right-most node (biggest number) .. print that remembering the rest of the tree ... but to remember the tree without the right-most node and then recursing it would reqiure me to mutate (use (set! ... )) ... which i cant use :S ... How would i recurse this properly ?

Comment: Don't worry about printing the first line first; the surprise in a recursive program is that if you take care of your immediate children, then everything gets taken care of (because your immediate children will take care of *their* immediate children). So the question is this: what *additional* information do you need, beside the subtree itself, to print the subtree correctly? In this example: take a look at the first two lines, that correspond to the left subtree. The left subtree contains a node with 6 and a single child with five. oops, going to next comment....